# Android Studio terminal not opening/working

Tags: android-studio, command-line, terminal, winpty

I got following error while trying to open Android Studio terminal.

---

```
Cannot open Local Terminal
Failed to start [cmd.exe] in D:/NirapodBima

See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.
```

---

As per error log instruction went to idea.log file and found following error. Error log says winpty executable file is missing but I've no idea how to solve this error. Tried Android Studio as Administration mode as well but no luck.

```
2020-06-15 07:48:44,841 [2404236]   INFO - m.pty4j.windows.WindowsVersion - Windows version: 6.3.9600 
2020-06-15 07:48:44,845 [2404240]   INFO - erminal.AbstractTerminalRunner - Cannot open Local Terminal 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Failed to start [cmd.exe] in D:/NirapodBima
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:48)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.AbstractTerminalRunner.lambda$openSessionInDirectory$4(AbstractTerminalRunner.java:208)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY
    at com.pty4j.windows.WinPtyProcess.<init>(WinPtyProcess.java:75)
    at com.pty4j.windows.WinPtyProcess.<init>(WinPtyProcess.java:50)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcessBuilder.start(PtyProcessBuilder.java:109)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcess.exec(PtyProcess.java:78)
    at com.pty4j.PtyProcess.exec(PtyProcess.java:49)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.terminal.LocalTerminalDirectRunner.createProcess(LocalTerminalDirectRunner.java:217)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.pty4j.PtyException: Error starting winpty: agent executable does not exist: 'F:\D-drive\1\lib\pty4j-native\win\x86_64\winpty-agent.exe'
    at com.pty4j.windows.WinPty.<init>(WinPty.java:93)
    at com.pty4j.windows.WinPtyProcess.<init>(WinPtyProcess.java:72)
    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I believe its related to Anti-Virus or Real-time scanner which prevents "winpty-agent.exe" from running. It is believed to fix the issue, if you white-list this  executable and related "winpty.dll" files. Below are the paths for "winpty-agent.exe":

**C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\pty4j-native\win\x86_64**

Read more from below links:

1. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-220774
2. https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/255580-ransomware-protection-breaks-terminal-in-android-studio-intellij/